# Backpax - set image data attribute (data-img) after initialization

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I use background images to break up multiple sections on a webpage. I want those images to display parallax effect whereby page content flows over the images faster than the images move themselves. I want to use the [backpax script](https://appleple.github.io/backpax/) for this.

The HTML of the div where the magic happens looks as follows:

HTML

```
<div class="js-parallax"
data-img="url">
</div>
```

The background image is referred to using the data attribute `data-img`.

I've placed four of these divs in the snippet. The latter two have an empty data-img attribute, I want to set.

I have a folder with a broad spectrum of images I can set as a background.
I want to use JavaScript to randomly use one image as the parallax image. (or multiple if I set numerous div with the `class="js.parallax"` Thus, on page load a relative url to a random image has to be appended to the `data-img attribute`

The script I use looks as follows: (I used 3 links to Unsplash images here instead of relative urls to local folder)

When I use this script it only shows the background color for those two divs with an empty data-img attribute.

However, when I open the deloper tools or resize the browser window on my desktop the random images are loaded. Not in this code snippet however!

How is this possible? Do I have something askew in the order of my JavaScript? Or has the DOM not loaded yet?

How can I solve this problem so that the random images are loaded directly on page loaded.

```js
new Backpax('.js-parallax')


$(document).ready(function () {
    var imagesPara = ['https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507525428034-b723cf961d3e?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1473&q=80', 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1515016454727-48ddf26ac789?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1471&q=80', 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494396550299-e4eb26401c8b?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1471&q=80' 
    ];

    $('.js-parallax').each(function () {
        var randomImage = imagesPara[Math.floor(Math.random() * imagesPara.length)];
        $(this).attr({
            'data-img': '../_assets/img/background-img/' + randomImage + ''
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.js-parallax {
  background-image: ;
  background-color: blue;
  height: calc(100vh - 60vh);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+sLIOodYLS7CIrQpBjl+C7nPvqq+FbNUBDunl/OZv93DB7Ln/533i8e/mZXLi/P+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/backpax@latest/bundle/backpax.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm-10 offset-sm-1" role="main">


        <h1>Some Title</h1>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Hic nobis ipsum aut fugiat molestiae est impedit officia At perferendis quisquam est illo molestiae cum minus corrupti. Ab numquam corporis qui corporis temporibus in numquam deleniti. Ut maxime expedita quo facilis
          unde aut earum eaque non sunt porro ut ipsa blanditiis</p>

        <div class="js-parallax" data-img="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1565275706395-d452122d6cfc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80">
          <p>contents here</p>
        </div>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Hic nobis ipsum aut fugiat molestiae est impedit officia At perferendis quisquam est illo molestiae cum minus corrupti. Ab numquam corporis qui corporis temporibus in numquam deleniti. Ut maxime expedita quo facilis
          unde aut earum eaque non sunt porro ut ipsa blanditiis</p>

        <hr>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Hic nobis ipsum aut fugiat molestiae est impedit officia At perferendis quisquam est illo molestiae cum minus corrupti. Ab numquam corporis qui corporis temporibus in numquam deleniti. Ut maxime expedita quo facilis
          unde aut earum eaque non sunt porro ut ipsa blanditiis</p>

        <div class="js-parallax" data-img="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533130061792-64b345e4a833?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80">
        </div>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Hic nobis ipsum aut fugiat molestiae est impedit officia At perferendis quisquam est illo molestiae cum minus corrupti. Ab numquam corporis qui corporis temporibus in numquam deleniti. Ut maxime expedita quo facilis
          unde aut earum eaque non sunt porro ut ipsa blanditiis</p>

        <hr>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Hic nobis ipsum aut fugiat molestiae est impedit officia At perferendis quisquam est illo molestiae cum minus corrupti. Ab numquam corporis qui corporis temporibus in numquam deleniti. Ut maxime expedita quo facilis
          unde aut earum eaque non sunt porro ut ipsa blanditiis</p>
        <div class="js-parallax" data-img="">

        </div>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Hic nobis ipsum aut fugiat molestiae est impedit officia At perferendis quisquam est illo molestiae cum minus corrupti. Ab numquam corporis qui corporis temporibus in numquam deleniti. Ut maxime expedita quo facilis
          unde aut earum eaque non sunt porro ut ipsa blanditiis</p>

        <hr>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Hic nobis ipsum aut fugiat molestiae est impedit officia At perferendis quisquam est illo molestiae cum minus corrupti. Ab numquam corporis qui corporis temporibus in numquam deleniti. Ut maxime expedita quo facilis
          unde aut earum eaque non sunt porro ut ipsa blanditiis</p>
        <div class="js-parallax" data-img="">

        </div>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Hic nobis ipsum aut fugiat molestiae est impedit officia At perferendis quisquam est illo molestiae cum minus corrupti. Ab numquam corporis qui corporis temporibus in numquam deleniti. Ut maxime expedita quo facilis
          unde aut earum eaque non sunt porro ut ipsa blanditiis</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like backpax does not watch the `data-img` field, so assign alone does not reload the image.

You can trigger a `resize` event, which will cause an update in backpax:

```
$('.js-parallax').each(function () {
  var randomImage = imagesPara[Math.floor(Math.random() * imagesPara.length)];
  $(this).attr({'data-img': randomImage});
});
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize')); // <-------- trigger reload
```

Or you can do manually what a resize triggers:

```
const backpax = new Backpax('.js-parallax')
...
$('.js-parallax').each(function () {
  var randomImage = imagesPara[Math.floor(Math.random() * imagesPara.length)];
  $(this).attr({'data-img': randomImage});
  const index = Array.from(backpax.elements).findIndex(e => e === this)
  const id = this.dataset.id
  const insert = document.getElementById(id);
  backpax.setBestImg(this, insert, index);
});
```

Both work, the latter is more efficient but also more fragile.

With `resize`:

```js
new Backpax('.js-parallax')


$(document).ready(function() {
  var imagesPara = ['https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507525428034-b723cf961d3e?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1473&q=80', 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1515016454727-48ddf26ac789?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1471&q=80', 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494396550299-e4eb26401c8b?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1471&q=80'];

  $('.js-parallax').each(function() {
    var randomImage = imagesPara[Math.floor(Math.random() * imagesPara.length)];
    $(this).attr({
      'data-img': randomImage
    });
  });
  window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
});
```

```css
.js-parallax {
  background-image: ;
  background-color: blue;
  height: calc(100vh - 60vh);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+sLIOodYLS7CIrQpBjl+C7nPvqq+FbNUBDunl/OZv93DB7Ln/533i8e/mZXLi/P+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/backpax@latest/bundle/backpax.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm-10 offset-sm-1" role="main">


        <h1>Some Title</h1>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Hic nobis ipsum aut fugiat molestiae est impedit officia At perferendis quisquam est illo molestiae cum minus corrupti. Ab numquam corporis qui corporis temporibus in numquam deleniti. Ut maxime expedita quo facilis
          unde aut earum eaque non sunt porro ut ipsa blanditiis</p>

        <div class="js-parallax" data-img="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1565275706395-d452122d6cfc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80">
          <p>contents here</p>
        </div>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Hic nobis ipsum aut fugiat molestiae est impedit officia At perferendis quisquam est illo molestiae cum minus corrupti. Ab numquam corporis qui corporis temporibus in numquam deleniti. Ut maxime expedita quo facilis
          unde aut earum eaque non sunt porro ut ipsa blanditiis</p>

        <hr>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Hic nobis ipsum aut fugiat molestiae est impedit officia At perferendis quisquam est illo molestiae cum minus corrupti. Ab numquam corporis qui corporis temporibus in numquam deleniti. Ut maxime expedita quo facilis
          unde aut earum eaque non sunt porro ut ipsa blanditiis</p>

        <div class="js-parallax" data-img="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533130061792-64b345e4a833?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80">
        </div>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Hic nobis ipsum aut fugiat molestiae est impedit officia At perferendis quisquam est illo molestiae cum minus corrupti. Ab numquam corporis qui corporis temporibus in numquam deleniti. Ut maxime expedita quo facilis
          unde aut earum eaque non sunt porro ut ipsa blanditiis</p>

        <hr>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Hic nobis ipsum aut fugiat molestiae est impedit officia At perferendis quisquam est illo molestiae cum minus corrupti. Ab numquam corporis qui corporis temporibus in numquam deleniti. Ut maxime expedita quo facilis
          unde aut earum eaque non sunt porro ut ipsa blanditiis</p>
        <div class="js-parallax" data-img="">

        </div>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Hic nobis ipsum aut fugiat molestiae est impedit officia At perferendis quisquam est illo molestiae cum minus corrupti. Ab numquam corporis qui corporis temporibus in numquam deleniti. Ut maxime expedita quo facilis
          unde aut earum eaque non sunt porro ut ipsa blanditiis</p>

        <hr>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Hic nobis ipsum aut fugiat molestiae est impedit officia At perferendis quisquam est illo molestiae cum minus corrupti. Ab numquam corporis qui corporis temporibus in numquam deleniti. Ut maxime expedita quo facilis
          unde aut earum eaque non sunt porro ut ipsa blanditiis</p>
        <div class="js-parallax" data-img="">

        </div>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Hic nobis ipsum aut fugiat molestiae est impedit officia At perferendis quisquam est illo molestiae cum minus corrupti. Ab numquam corporis qui corporis temporibus in numquam deleniti. Ut maxime expedita quo facilis
          unde aut earum eaque non sunt porro ut ipsa blanditiis</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

With manual setup:

```js
const backpax = new Backpax('.js-parallax')


$(document).ready(function() {
  var imagesPara = ['https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507525428034-b723cf961d3e?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1473&q=80', 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1515016454727-48ddf26ac789?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1471&q=80', 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494396550299-e4eb26401c8b?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1471&q=80'];

  $('.js-parallax').each(function() {
    var randomImage = imagesPara[Math.floor(Math.random() * imagesPara.length)];
    $(this).attr({
      'data-img': randomImage
    });
    const index = Array.from(backpax.elements).findIndex(e => e === this)
    const id = this.dataset.id
    const insert = document.getElementById(id);
    backpax.setBestImg(this, insert, index);
  });
});
```

```css
.js-parallax {
  background-image: ;
  background-color: blue;
  height: calc(100vh - 60vh);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+sLIOodYLS7CIrQpBjl+C7nPvqq+FbNUBDunl/OZv93DB7Ln/533i8e/mZXLi/P+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/backpax@latest/bundle/backpax.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm-10 offset-sm-1" role="main">


        <h1>Some Title</h1>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Hic nobis ipsum aut fugiat molestiae est impedit officia At perferendis quisquam est illo molestiae cum minus corrupti. Ab numquam corporis qui corporis temporibus in numquam deleniti. Ut maxime expedita quo facilis
          unde aut earum eaque non sunt porro ut ipsa blanditiis</p>

        <div class="js-parallax" data-img="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1565275706395-d452122d6cfc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80">
          <p>contents here</p>
        </div>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Hic nobis ipsum aut fugiat molestiae est impedit officia At perferendis quisquam est illo molestiae cum minus corrupti. Ab numquam corporis qui corporis temporibus in numquam deleniti. Ut maxime expedita quo facilis
          unde aut earum eaque non sunt porro ut ipsa blanditiis</p>

        <hr>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Hic nobis ipsum aut fugiat molestiae est impedit officia At perferendis quisquam est illo molestiae cum minus corrupti. Ab numquam corporis qui corporis temporibus in numquam deleniti. Ut maxime expedita quo facilis
          unde aut earum eaque non sunt porro ut ipsa blanditiis</p>

        <div class="js-parallax" data-img="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533130061792-64b345e4a833?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80">
        </div>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Hic nobis ipsum aut fugiat molestiae est impedit officia At perferendis quisquam est illo molestiae cum minus corrupti. Ab numquam corporis qui corporis temporibus in numquam deleniti. Ut maxime expedita quo facilis
          unde aut earum eaque non sunt porro ut ipsa blanditiis</p>

        <hr>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Hic nobis ipsum aut fugiat molestiae est impedit officia At perferendis quisquam est illo molestiae cum minus corrupti. Ab numquam corporis qui corporis temporibus in numquam deleniti. Ut maxime expedita quo facilis
          unde aut earum eaque non sunt porro ut ipsa blanditiis</p>
        <div class="js-parallax" data-img="">

        </div>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Hic nobis ipsum aut fugiat molestiae est impedit officia At perferendis quisquam est illo molestiae cum minus corrupti. Ab numquam corporis qui corporis temporibus in numquam deleniti. Ut maxime expedita quo facilis
          unde aut earum eaque non sunt porro ut ipsa blanditiis</p>

        <hr>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Hic nobis ipsum aut fugiat molestiae est impedit officia At perferendis quisquam est illo molestiae cum minus corrupti. Ab numquam corporis qui corporis temporibus in numquam deleniti. Ut maxime expedita quo facilis
          unde aut earum eaque non sunt porro ut ipsa blanditiis</p>
        <div class="js-parallax" data-img="">

        </div>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Hic nobis ipsum aut fugiat molestiae est impedit officia At perferendis quisquam est illo molestiae cum minus corrupti. Ab numquam corporis qui corporis temporibus in numquam deleniti. Ut maxime expedita quo facilis
          unde aut earum eaque non sunt porro ut ipsa blanditiis</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```